# Why does the startDate get increased along with the currentDate?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why in the following script, the startDate changes along with the currentDate, but name1 remains the same.

```
getWorkdays('01/03/2017', '05/03/2017', 'Jimmy');
function getWorkdays (startDate, endDate, name1) {

    var startDate = nlapiStringToDate(startDate);
    var endDate = nlapiStringToDate(endDate);
    var name1 = name1;

    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Conversion of String to Date', 'startDate is now ' + startDate + ' and endDate ' + endDate + ' and the name is ' + name1);

    var name2 = name1;
    var currentDate = startDate;
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', '', 'The currentDate is'+ currentDate + ' and the startDate is ' + startDate);

        while (currentDate <= endDate) { // Loop through all dates between startDate and endDate

        var weekday = currentDate.getDay(); // Retrieve the weekday (in numeric format with sunday = 0) from the currentDate

        if (weekday == 1 || weekday == 6){ // Perform the following loop only if weekday is a Saturday or Sunday

            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', '', 'The weekday number is ' + weekday + ' and the name is ' + name2);

        }

        var name2 = 'Jose';
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1); // Go to the next date
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', '', 'name2 is '+ name2 + ' and name1 ' + name1);
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', '', 'The currentDate is'+ currentDate + ' and the startDate is ' + startDate);
    }
}
```

How can the startDate be kept at 01/03/2017?

Answer (score 1):

After

```
var currentDate = startDate;
```

both `currentDate` and `startDate` variables point to the same `Date` object, so changes made to one variable affect the other variable as well (both "see" the same object).

After

```
var name2 = 'Jose';
```

`name2` variable points to a new string, but this doesn't change what `name1` points to. To achieve the same effect as above, you would have to make changes to the original string (which is not possible in JavaScript, because strings are immutable).

> How can the startDate be kept at 01/03/2017?

You will need to create a new `Date` object and initialize `currentDate` using that object.

```
var currentDate = nlapiStringToDate(startDate);
```

Comment: Or create a new Date object based on `startDate` and asign it to `currentDate` if he removes that line his code will break.

Comment: What about the date method .clone()? Could that be used as well and one?